# Can Amplitude track event from keyboard extension?

Tags: swift3, custom-keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I can track/record event from container app by Amplitude. I use the code bellow

```
Amplitude.instance().logEvent("Launch")
```

but when I write the bellow line

```
Amplitude.instance().logEvent("Share Catmoji Keyboard Extension")
```

in keyboard extension

The event does not record in amplitude dashboard.

Can anyone faced this issue? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can log events from App Extensions. I know this works in share extensions in production. You have to initialize Amplitude in the `viewDidLoad` of the principal view controller. According to the Amplitude docs this should work for all App Extensions except WatchOS, so I would imagine if you intialize Amplitude in your `UIInputViewController` subclass's `viewDidLoad` method it would work:

`Amplitude.instance().initializeApiKey("{YOUR_API_KEY}")`